# Flash - Why doesn't my SharedObject get saved on disk when closing IE?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, save, disk, flush, shared-objects

I have a Flash application that uses SharedObject to save and read some data locally. As it is said everywhere Flash saves the data from the shared object to disk when the application is closed. And indeed it does when I test it with the stand-alone Flash Player or all of these browsers: Firefox, Opera, Safari, Chrome, Flock... But it doesn't work when I use IE (I've tried IE6 and IE7).

Does anyone know anything about this issue? Why might it be happening... and how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [MultipleIEs](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) or standalone versions of the IE browsers? I've had issues with that as it seems they don't work properly when installed together.

The best way to be sure is testing your application on someone else's computer with only one version of IE installed.

**EDIT:** Check out the hints below:

It seems that if you install things in a special order evrything seems to work better.

1. Install/upgrade to IE8
2. Install standalone IE7
3. Install MultipleIEs (IE6 and below)

Also check the IE Collection (finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm) tool instead of MultipleIEs for better results.